# What is this syntax - public static 9000?

Tags: java, syntax

Reading the article on http://www.jamesward.com/2011/08/23/war-less-java-web-apps on how to embed an app server with your application, i noticed this bit of code.

```
package foo;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.StringUtil;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class Main
{

  public static 9900;">);
    out.close();
  }
}
```

What is the Main class doing as i dont understand that syntax.

Comment: Looks like your browser is borked somewhere... that page doesn't have that code as far as I can see.

Comment: This is not any type of syntax of Java

Comment: Thanks it looks like the page does not display correctly in Firefox.

Comment: Works for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see this, so it has to be a problem with your browser.

```
package foo;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.StringUtil;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class Main
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();

    root.setContextPath("/");
    root.setDescriptor(webappDirLocation + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    root.setResourceBase(webappDirLocation);

    root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    server.setHandler(root);

    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not compilable source code

Also there is no such source code available from the link you provided

Comment: Thanks. The page works fine in IE. I didnt realise it was a browser issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static 9900;">);
```

The above is no legal code, it may be some issue with your browse.
Which browser are you using anyways....